# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules. Discord,js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, status

**Error:**

> **SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules**

> **[Photo error]** https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0hWM.png

```
const client = require('../index.js');

client.on('ready', () => {
  let servers = await client.guilds.cache.size
  let servercount = await client.guilds.cache.reduce((a,b) => a+b.memberCount, 0)

  const activites = [
    `?help | ${servers} servers`,
    `Invite me now! | Watching ${servercount} members`
  ]

  setInterval(()=>{
    const status = activities[Math.floor(Math.random()*activities.length)]
    client.user.setPresence({ activities : [{name : `${status}`}]})
  }, 5000)

  
  console.log(`✅ ${client.user.tag} is ready`)
})
```

Comment: Please copy paste the content of your image, it's hard to read or impossible to read it for some other person.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use await with only async functions. Checkout the below code where I have changed your client.on callback function to async.

```js
const client = require('../index.js');

client.on('ready', async() => {
  let servers = await client.guilds.cache.size
  let servercount = await client.guilds.cache.reduce((a,b) => a+b.memberCount, 0)

  const activites = [
    `?help | ${servers} servers`,
    `Invite me now! | Watching ${servercount} members`
  ]

  setInterval(()=>{
    const status = activities[Math.floor(Math.random()*activities.length)]
    client.user.setPresence({ activities : [{name : `${status}`}]})
  }, 5000)

  
  console.log(`✅ ${client.user.tag} is ready`)
})
```